# Using generics in C# with a "recursive" relationship

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to implement a Master/Slave relationship in C# (basically a Master has a list of slaves and each Slave has only one master) and in Java I can do this:

```
class Master<S extends Slave> {

}

class Slave<M extends Master> {

}
```

However, an equivalent idiom in C#:

```
class Master<S> where S:Slave {

}

class Slave<M> where M:Master {

}
```

Does not compile as it requires me to use the generic on the where condition and I don't know how to specify *this exact type*; how can this be done?

Furthermore, how can I implement a class that is both a Master of a collection and a Slave to another master (since C# - and Java for that matter - has no multiple inheritance)?

Something like:

```
class MasterSlave<M,S>: Master<M>, Slave<S> {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: For your multiple inheritance dilemma, seems like an interface would make most sense there, since you can implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Master<M, S> where S : Slave<S, M> where M : Master<M, S>
```

Comment: Now the fun part.  Can you provide the code to create an instance of this type?

Comment: @Servy: `class MyMaster : Master<MyMaster, MySlave` and `class MySlave : Slave<MySlave, MyMaster>`.  It's a more convoluted form of the CRTP.

Comment: @Charleh: It's a poor substitute for higher-kinded types.

Comment: Dear god... this is .. masterful.

Comment: Yeah but in the absence of these features it's what we've got to work with until they add it in the next version of the language!

Answer (score 2):

If your setup is exactly as you've listed, then it's because  you don't have regular, non-generic `Master` and `Slave` classes. You could, however, do something like this:

```
class Master
{

}

class Master<S> : Master
    where S : Slave
{

}

class Slave
{

}

class Slave<M> : Slave
    where M : Master
{

}
```

And then a hypothetical `MasterSlave` class could look like this:

```
class MasterSlave<M,S>: 
    where M : Master
    where S : Slave
{

}
```

(note, as was pointed out in the comments below, you could also use interfaces here instead of non-generic classes)

That may seem redundant, but trust me, when it comes time to actually create instances of your classes, it will be far simpler than the alternative.

Based on your initial goal, however, I'm not sure why you need generics at all:

> I'm trying to implement a Master/Slave relationship in C# (basically a **Master has a list of slaves and each Slave has only one master**)

It sounds like you're just trying to implement a simple one-to-many relationship, which can be achieved like this:

```
class Master
{
    List<Slave> Slaves { get; set; }
}

class Slave
{
    Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I feel reluctant to answer because I want to say 90% of exactly what you said, however the only change I would do is use Interfaces instead of base non generic classes, that way MasterSlave would just be `class MasterSlave : IMaster, ISlave`

Comment: I agree, both interfaces and abstract classes would work great here. I was trying to keep it fairly simple, though, and get to the root of the issue he was having.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand "(basically a Master has a list of slaves and each Slave has only one master)" correctly, this is simple inheritance:

```
class Master { ... }

class Slave : Master {...}
class Slave2 : Master {...}

// Instantiate:
Master master;
Slave slave;

master = new Master();
slave = new Slave2();
slave = new Slave();
```

I would usually code it like:

```
class Master { ... }
class abstract Slave : Master {...}
class Slave1 : Slave {...}
class Slave2 : Slave {...}
```

So I could put functionality into the Slave class, but not instantiate it.